# Display a Loading Sign while a model is being trained in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret, shinydashboard

I am making a Shiny App in which, at the click of the actionButton, a model is trained using the caret package. As this training takes time - approximately 4-5 minutes - I wanted to display a loading sign or a loading GIF in the App where results are displayed after the model is trained. Otherwise, the User wouldn't know what is happening or when the model is trained.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is loading spinner which you can use in your ui.R

```
# loading the library
library(shinycssloaders)
withSpinner()

# For example, if you have the plot for which you would like to show loading spinner before it's gets drawn while making some data manipulation 
withSpinner(plotOutput("my_plot"))
```

You can find more information about it on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinycssloaders/README.html

Comment: This is an Awesome answer ! Didn't thought it was That easy. Thanks brother @Santosh ...

Comment: Dear @Santosh, could you tell me if it is possible to embed a Progress Bar, instead of a Loading GIF while training an ML model using the caret package ?

Comment: Please post a new question about it and I will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a progress bar.  Examples are here:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html

Comment: dear brother, I have seen this as well as other articles from Shiny but a) they were very confusing and b) they only gave examples of DataTables and some other stuff which wasn't very helpful for me for using the Model Training functions ...